# order of operations division wont work with javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to convert 75 degrees fahrenheit to celsius. 
Instead of giving me an answer that is somewhere around 24 it keeps giving me 57. I cant figure out how to do the order of operations thing where it first subtracts the 32 and then divides that answer by 1.8. Parenthesis around the /1.8 does not work.
I feel like this shouldnt have to be in a function because its so simple but I could be wrong. Here is my code:

```
var tempNumber = 75;
var celsius = tempNumber - 32 / 1.8;

console.log(celsius);  // 57.22222222222222
```

Comment: It’s `(tempNumber - 32) / 1.8`. Basic math.

Comment: [BODMAS](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html) - or, specifically for javascript [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Please be polite @Xufox. You were a beginner once.

Comment: @DuncanThacker - I don't think that was rude, one would assume someone who is engaged in programming would have an understanding of elementary maths

Comment: I got confused and overthought the whole thing. Sorry.

Comment: @suzyc—you should accept an answer if there's one that suits, or delete the question if you think it won't be helpful.

Comment: The question is trivial and should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = (tempnumber-32)/1.8;
```

You want the grouping around the subtraction because you want that to happen first

Answer (score 1):

BODMAS is the key. the division is taking precedence because you didnt put brackets around the subtraction.
`C = (f-32)/1.8`

Brackets (parts of a calculation inside brackets always come first).
Orders (numbers involving powers or square roots).
Division.
Multiplication.
Addition.
Subtraction.

Read more at: https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html

Comment: BODMAS is misleading: division and multiplication have equal precedence (in `3 * 2 / 6` the division does not happen first), they are evaluated left to right. Same for addition and subtraction (in mathematics and ECMAScript).

Comment: this is true, thats why so many also call it bomdas, etc. but i was referencing more to the fact that brackets has precedence over multiplication/division and that division/multiplication has precedence over addition and subtraction. 

a more realistic representation would be: B->O->(D|M)->(A|S)